# combining bash and SQL scripting to create wordpress sites

Tags: mysql, linux, wordpress, bash, ubuntu

I am writing a script that will run on a `Ubuntu 16.04.1` server. The purpose of the script is to install a wordpress site on the server. I took most of my scripting from [this site](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-multiple-wordpress-sites-on-a-single-ubuntu-vps).

I am trying to create and grant permissions on the database, however my script stops when I enter a mysql environment using `mysql -u root -p`. As well, variables created in the bash environment are not carried over to the `mysql` environment. Here is my script for this section.

```
echo "Please enter the Name of the Database(please make name relevant)"    
read -p DBNAME

echo "Please enter the Name of the Database User(Please document username)"
read -p DBUSER

echo "Please enter a Database password(Please document password)"
read -p DBPASSWORD

a=\'

b=$a$DBPASSWORD$a

f='CREATE DATABASE '$DBNAME' CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci'

g=$a$f$a
c='GRANT ALL ON '$DBNAME.*'TO '$DBUSER'@localhost'' IDENTIFIED BY '$b  
d=$a$c$a

mysql -u root -p -e $g    
mysql -u root -p -e $c    
mysql -u root -p -e "FLUSH PRIVILEGES"
```

Any help integrating the environment changes together would be great

Comment: You might want to read up on SQL injection attacks. You are opening yourself up to one by blindly using the values of `DBNAME`, `DBUSER`, and `DBPASSWORD` in your constructed SQL commands.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I will look into this.

Answer (score 0):

1. When defining `f` and `c` use double quotes. Single quotes don't allow your variables to expand.
2. You log the user in as root to mysql, but don't supply a password, so it will prompt. Perhaps ask for the root password as well.

Perhaps something like the following would do the trick:

```
echo "Please enter the Name of the Database(please make name relevant)"    
read -p DBNAME

echo "Please enter the Name of the Database User(Please document username)"
read -p DBUSER

echo "Please enter a Database password(Please document password)"
read -p DBPASSWORD

echo "Please enter your database's root password"
read -p DBROOTPASSWORD

a=\'

b=$a$DBPASSWORD$a

f="CREATE DATABASE '$DBNAME' CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci"

g=$a$f$a
c="GRANT ALL ON $DBNAME.* TO $DBUSER@localhost IDENTIFIED BY "$b  
d=$a$c$a

mysql -u root -p"$DBROOTPASSWORD" -e $g    
mysql -u root -p"$DBROOTPASSWORD" -e $c    
mysql -u root -p"$DBROOTPASSWORD" -e "FLUSH PRIVILEGES"
```